# How to fix Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

Tags: sql, database

this SQl statement is throwing error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.` I am not exactly sure what is the issue. It is just a update statement and I am trying to get the user_id from another table where user_name is this.

statement:

```
update esg.client_user_pref where client_user_id = (select U.CLIENT_USER_ID from esg.CLIENT_USER U where U.USER_NAME='CorpESignClientUser') and pref_entity = 'UsageMode' and pref_attrb = 'ExpirationAfterDay' set pref_value = '15';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for UPDATE query is

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

Answer (score 3):

wrong sequence:

right: update ... set ... where ...

wrong: update ... where .... set

Answer (score 0):

AS per your code above this should do the trick

```
     update table esg.client_user_pref 
 set pref_value = '15'
 where client_user_id = 
 (select U.CLIENT_USER_ID from esg.CLIENT_USER U where U.USER_NAME='CorpESignClientUser') 
 and pref_entity = 'UsageMode' and pref_attrb = 'ExpirationAfterDay' ;
```

Comment: Thanks MRIT, this is how I did it. :)

Comment: Thats ok, no problem